# How to interpret the expression « n’en savoir pas un traître mot »

Tags: expressions

> Cette arme relève d’un projet top secret lancé par le président actuel. Monique **n’en sait pas un traître mot**.

Usually, the expression « pas un traître mot » is used with the meaning of "not even a single word", as in "You haven’t heard a single word I said!".

In this particular sentence, however, the expression seems to mean more like "she doesn’t have the slightest idea about it" or "she has no idea of its existence".

Comment: The *en* refers to the preceding statement: *Elle ne sait pas un traître mot du fait que cette arme relève d'un projet top secret lancé par le président actuel.* NB. It is more common to place *pas* before the infinitive form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, in this context, "pas un traître mot" means that she doesn't have the slightest idea about it. However, litteraly speaking, I would translate it by "she hasn't heard a single word about it", ie she is not aware.

This expression is relatively uncommon, only seen in litterature, and less used with the meaning "not a single word".

Comment: Hi. By this expression being uncommon, do you refer specifically to an instance where it is used with "savoir", or every instance where « pas un traître mot » is used, coupled with any verb? Merci.

Comment: I refer to the expression in general, it's a very formal register. I don't think there's a lot of use of "un traître mot" without verbs like "savoir", "comprendre", or, more rarely, penser.

Comment: It's definitively too formal. I would use "pas le moindre mot" or "pas un seul mot".